# If else statement with multiple conditions and 4 outcomes

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to classify species based on commonness. There are 4 classifications:

1. Rare - frequency<mean & relative abundance<mean
2. Occasional - frequency<mean & relative abundance>mean
3. Common - frequency>mean & relative abundance<mean
4. Dominant - frequency>mean & relative abundance>mean

I am trying to create an if else statement to add a column with these classifications to my data frame which looks like

```
species <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
relabund <- c(.5, .11, .23, .06, .36, .19) #relative abundance
freq <- c(6, 3, 20, 2, 11, 4) #number of sites species occurs at
df = data.frame(species, relabund, freq)
```

I've tried something like this:

```
if (df[,2]>mean(relabund) && df[,3]>mean(freq)) {
    df$Classification = "Dominant"
  } else if (df[,2]<mean(relabund) && df[,3]<mean(freq)) {
    df$Classification = "Rare"
  } else if (df[,2]<mean(relabund) && df[,3]>mean(freq)) {
    df$Classification = "Common"
  } else 
    df$Classification = "Occasional"
```

But this doesn't work as it classifies all species as "Rare". I'm very new to if else statements so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get "Occaisonal" using your code.

Your `if` statements are looking at logical vectors, but returning one value for ALL rows, for example:

`df[,2]` is the whole column: `0.50 0.11 0.23 0.06 0.36 0.19`

`df[,2]>mean(relabund)` returns a logical vector of:

`TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE`

by using `&&` you are performing a logical comparison to two logical vectors. As these vectors aren't the same, you always get false:

`df[,2]>mean(relabund) && df[,3]>mean(freq)`

`==`

`c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) && c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)`

`==`

`FALSE`

Also, `df$Classification` sets the column to be the same value, i.e. it's working on the whole dataset rather than row by row. What you need to do it perform vector operations on each row.

Using `dplyr` from the `tidyverse` you can get an easier to read answer (for some!)

```
library(tidyverse)

species <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
relabund <- c(.5, .11, .23, .06, .36, .19) #relative abundance
freq <- c(6, 3, 20, 2, 11, 4) #number of sites species occurs at
df = data.frame(species, relabund, freq)

df %>% 
  mutate(classify = 
           ifelse(freq < mean(freq) & relabund < mean(relabund),
                  "Rare",
           ifelse(freq < mean(freq) & relabund > mean(relabund),
                  "Occaisonal",
           ifelse(freq > mean(freq) & relabund < mean(relabund),
                 "Common",
           ifelse(freq > mean(freq) & relabund > mean(relabund),
                 "Dominant",
                 "ERROR")))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even think about the fact that those arguments returned logicals. I'm trying to get into using tidyverse, much cleaner!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `case_when`, where the `if` is on the left side of `~` and to the right is the value you want to assign to that condition.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(classify = case_when(freq < mean(freq) & relabund < mean(relabund) ~ "Rare",
                              freq < mean(freq) & relabund > mean(relabund) ~ "Occaisonal",
                              freq > mean(freq) & relabund < mean(relabund) ~ "Common",
                              freq > mean(freq) & relabund > mean(relabund) ~ "Dominant",
                              TRUE ~ "ERROR"))
```

**Output**

```
  species relabund freq   classify
1       a     0.50    6 Occaisonal
2       b     0.11    3       Rare
3       c     0.23   20     Common
4       d     0.06    2       Rare
5       e     0.36   11   Dominant
6       f     0.19    4       Rare
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(species = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), relabund = c(0.5, 
0.11, 0.23, 0.06, 0.36, 0.19), freq = c(6, 3, 20, 2, 11, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```